# Conditionally delete nested documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nested

I have a basic document structure like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6144f74c066fee820d28b34f"),
    "Login" : ISODate("2021-09-16T21:09:00.000Z"),
    "DiaryNotes" : [ 
        {
            "Message" : "Metus tincidunt ultricies.",
            "Timestamp" : ISODate("1922-07-29T01:42:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Message" : "Ligula, eleifend ultrices, fames in, est aliquam ex congue.",
            "Timestamp" : ISODate("2022-01-09T12:48:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Message" : "Dignissim ante efficitur.",
            "Timestamp" : ISODate("1970-12-22T18:20:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Message" : "At, tellus erat, felis vulputate enim.",
            "Timestamp" : ISODate("1965-12-16T15:07:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
}
```

I'd like to be able to delete all the nested DiaryNotes documents where *Timestamp* falls before the *Login* date in the parent document. I've tried the query below but all the DiaryNotes end up disappearing:

```
db.getCollection('Surveys').updateMany(
{
    $expr: { $gt: ["$Login", "$DiaryNotes.Timestamp"] }
},
  {
     $pull:
        {
           DiaryNotes: { }
        }
  }
)
```

Can't seem to reference any parent fields from the $pull part of the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection('Surveys').updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      DiaryNotes: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$DiaryNotes",
          cond: { $lte: [ "$Login", "$$this.Timestamp" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I thought about solving this by using the positional operator, would you recommend using filter over that considering performance?

Comment: Are you concerned about the performance? I don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: Do you know the position? If yes, then why do you need condition `Login <= Timestamp`? If not, then you need compare Login and Timestamp in any case.

Comment: Thanks. This works great for Mongo 4.2+ and the only edit I'd suggest is changing the operator to $lt so that Timestamp is always before the Login. However, I didn't realise that my CosmosDB uses Mongo 4.0. Can this query be adjusted to work given that aggregation pipelines for updates are not supported with version 4.0?